# Connect ORACLE to SQLSERVER to REMOTE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, dblink

I have Sql server and oracle installed on same machine. So I created a heterogeneous connection between the two server. Now I need to do some transaction in my sql server and need to send the result to remote SQL Server. I tried achieve this by following steps,

1. Created a Link between Oracle and Sql server (Works fine)
2. Created a Link server in Sql server to connect Remote sql server (working)
3. So I rewrite the Sql server procedure to call remote server.

**Oracle Block**

```
DECLARE
c             INTEGER;
nr            INTEGER;
v_sql         VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN


    V_SQL :='EXEC dbo.TESTPROCEDURE ''test'',1';
    C  := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@SQLSERVER;
    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@SQLSERVER(C, V_SQL );
    NR := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@SQLSERVER(C);
    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@SQLSERVER(C);
    commit;   

END;
```

**Local Sql server**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTPROCEDURE] 
 @abc varchar(100),
 @xyx int,      
 AS    
DECLARE @result int
BEGIN     
SET @result = 1;                
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST VALUES(@abc)    
/**Some code**/    
EXEC @result =   REMOTESQL.[DATABASENAME].[dbo].[remoteproceduretest]  @abc, @xyz;           
END
```

When I tried to execute the oracle block I get the following error.

> Error report - ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle
>   system returned this message: ORA-02063: preceding line from SQLSERVER
>   ORA-06512: at line 14
>   28500. 00000 -  "connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:"
>   *Cause:    The cause is explained in the forwarded message.
>   *Action:   See the non-Oracle system's documentation of the forwarded
>              message.

Is it possible to call like above.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you prove that the connection bet. oracle and the first MSSQL db "works fine".  All 3 ORA- msgs are a bit generic, after googling all three myself (hint, hint) I'd suggest you  try googling ORA-28500.

Comment: @EdStevens HI mate, I tested it by executing a remote procedure in ms sql server from oracle server. I can able to communicate oracle to sql server , sql server to remote sql server. The problem arises  only when i tried below approach 
Oracle->local sql server->remote sql server